# Cannot create permanant environment variable in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a permanent environment variable on Ubuntu.

I tried the following:

```
export SASS_LIBSASS_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libsass
```

When I opened a new terminal and used 'printenv', I found the variable disappeared!

I also tried to make it work by appending:

```
SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass"
```

to the end of the file in `/etc/environment`, and then used:

```
source /etc/enviroment
```

That did not work!

**UPDATE:**

I then tried editing my ~/.profile file:

```
SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass"
```

that did not work.

I then tried instead appending the following at the end of `~/.profile` file:

```
export SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass"
```

that too did not work!

How can I make a permanent system variable?

Comment: You might want to use [fish](http://fishshell.com) as your shell. Look for its "universal scope variables"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` only sets the environment variable in your current shell session and any child processes started by that shell session. It is certainly not "permanent". The only way to set an environment variable for future shell sessions is to add the `export` command to a shell start-up file. Your best bet is probably to put it in `~/.profile` (unless the file `~/.bash_profile` exists).

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. Turned out that editing the enviroment file did not work either.

Comment: @YahyaUddin: Yeah, `/etc/environment` is not really where you want to put it.

Comment: I appened SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass" at the end of .profile. Still did not work. Is there another command I need to press for it to work?

Comment: @YahyaUddin: You need the export command. Just setting the variable isn't enough. And putting it in `.profile` will only cause the environment variable to be set the next time you start a shell session. If you want it to be immediate, you *also* have to type the export command in your current session.

Comment: So what do I need to do? add :  SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass"  to the end of the ~/.profile file. Then try the command: export $SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass" on the terminal. I tried that, did not work

Comment: note I also tried adding: export $SASS_LIBSASS_PATH="/usr/local/lib/libsass" to the ~/.profile file and that did not work either

Comment: There is no `$` in the export command. Look at the line in your own question.

Comment: I tired it without teh $ sign as well

Comment: When you edit that file, do the updates come straight away, or press a special command for it to run. I only tried restarting my terminal.

Comment: The file should be execute every time you start a bash shell (but not otherwise, so it doesn't take effect right away).

Comment: @rici: No, .profile is only sourced once at login, not for each new shell (that's .bashrc for bash shells). After modifying .profile you need to log out and in again.

Comment: oh okay. is that the same with the environment file, because that did not work either!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just seemed that I just needed a simple restart!